# Java abstract class not working as expected

Tags: java

Maybe this is a very basic question because I am a newbie in Java. Here I have one abstract class and its subclass, but the subclass variable value is not changing as per my expectation. Please let me know the reason

```
public abstract class NameEncrypt {
    public NameEncrypt(String n) {
        encryptn(n);
    }

    public abstract void setName(String n);

    public void encryptn(String n) {
        setName(n+"dummy");
    }
}
```

Now one `User` class as a subclass. I need to modify the `name` property with the help of the abstract class.

```
public class User extends NameEncrypt {
    private String name=null;

    public User(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        System.out.println("override=="+n);
        this.name=n;
    }
}
```

The test class is given below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        User user = new User("java");
        System.out.println("User clas name property is-"+user.getName());
    }
}
```

I expected 'javadummy' as output, but I am getting null as output. Why?

Have I misunderstand the abstract class concept?

Comment: Through the parent class constructor, the subclass `setName` is invoked before the `name` field initializer is executed. `name` is set to that value, then it's set to `null`.

Comment: thank you... @SotiriosDelimanolis